# GAE: Dynamic Properties Serving (db.Model) depending on Client (Biz App) using same application code

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine, bigdata

Let come to the point directly,

Consider here my Clients App name - **ABC** & **XYZ** with same application code.

Now let consider a db kind,

```
class user_details(db.Model):
   user_id = db.IntegerProperty()
   username = db.StringProperty()
   emailid = db.StringProperty()
   usertype = db.StringProperty()  #Require/used only in **ABC** app
   accesslevel = db.StringProperty() #Require/used only in **XYZ** app
   .
   .
```

then i realise while app serving same model structure for  both **ABC** and **XYZ** few properties are meaning less or like `usertype` for **XYZ** and `accesslevel` for **ABC**

So is that way to or trick so that i can serve only these properties which are actually require for an app. like ignoring `usertype` for **XYZ** or like ignoring `accesslevel` for **ABC**. so that i could save my db space.

**NOTE**: i go thru `db.Expando` method in gae doc. but i don't wanna use that db type in existing app. i would prefer `db.Model` only. because these app are already running over here. & it has around 2 billion records each client db.

Please suggest me suitable solution, if any one would have implemented these scenario.

I would appreciate your response on this.

Sincerely.

Niks

Answer (score 2):

I would create a base class for the common subset, and then subclass with the additions for each client. You should also consider namespaces to separate data for each client.  You have to know which client you are working with (hence namespace) and then load the appropriate model.

The other possibility would be to use a PolyModel but all subclasses are a aggregate of all properties.

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class UserBase(db.Model):
    user_id = db.IntegerProperty()
    username = db.StringProperty()
    emailid = db.StringProperty()

class UserABCDetails(UserBase):
    usertype = db.StringProperty() 

class UserXYZDetails(UserBase):
    accesslevel = db.StringProperty()
```

If you wanted to use a PolyModel you would just replace db.Model with db.PolyModel, but you should read up on the ramifications of that.

Comment: Thanks buddy, Could you please elaborate thru an example? so i can get a better idea about that.

Comment: Oh and if you starting out you should consider using ndb rather than db

Comment: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/polymodelclass#Introduction
Is that the same, i could do over here?

Comment: Yes, however you need to understand the differences.  When the base class is queried with db.Model you will not find any entities created with the subclass.  On the other hand with PolyModel if you did a query on the Base class, you will find all subclasses that match the criteria.  All instances of subclasses of a base class PolyModel are actually stored as the Base class.  Does that make sense ?